# Странности приведения .Net 4.6.1

Tags: c#, .net

Чтобы не вдаваться в детали самого кода, приведу более абстрактную ситуацию. Как мы все прекрасно знаем, следующий код вполне себе рабочий:

```
int a = 1;
double b = (double)a;
```

Рабочим он оставался и в таком случае:

```
int a = 1;
object b = a;
double c = (double)b;
```

(Ибо в объекте содержится int, a int к double приводится без проблем). Но каково же было моё удивление, когда аналогичный по сути кусок кода отказался работать на новом фреймворке. То есть на, грубо говоря, строке

```
double c = (double)b;
```

У меня вылетает ошибка, что такое приведение является недопустимым. Такое положение дел меня весьма расстроило и я, с грустным лицом временно запилив в ту строку Convert.ChangeType(), пошёл писать сюда сей вопрос дабы выяснить, что тут происходит.

---

Является ли данное "ужесточение" типизации не багом, а фичей, и лечится ли это как-нибудь более элегантно, нежели через вызов дополнительного метода из Convert?

Comment: Я не проверял такое привидение, но сейчас читаю Рихтера и там он описывал, что нельзя из объекта распаковать тип в желаемый, а нужно сначала привести к инту, а потом в даблу.

Comment: Конечно нельзя распаковать не то что вы запаковвли и если раньше это работало, то это был баг. Распаковывайте int и приводите к double уже потом

Comment: @Андрей Раньше приведение работало, как бы опуская один шаг, то есть оно приводило именно то, что в этом объекте упаковано. Я это использовал всегда, когда работал с <T> методами. Ибо мы не можем сделать, скажем, { T a = (T)b; }, даже если b приводится/на деле является этим самым T. На такие приведения компилятор всегда жаловался. По сему я выходил из ситуации так: { T a = (T)(object)b; }, такое приведение компилятор пропускал и оно всегда работало. А теперь эту маленькую элегантную строчку с парой приведений приходится менять на это: { T a = (T)Convert.ChangeType(b, typeof(T)); }

Comment: На предыдущих версиях это упало бы точно так же. Проверяйте.

Comment: @VladD Хм. Вы правы. Построил проект на базе 4.5, тоже выбрасывает ошибку. Либо у меня глюки, либо в методе чудесным образом T всегда совпадало с приводимом типом... ХД

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Понятно, что упаковка и распаковка/копирование снижают производитель-
>   ность приложения (в плане как замедления, так и расходования
>   дополнительной памяти), поэтому нужно знать, когда компилятор сам
>   создает код для выполнения этих операций, и стараться свести их к
>   минимуму. При распаковке упакованного значимого типа происходит
>   следующее.

1. > Если переменная, содержащая ссылку на упакованный значимый тип, равна null, генерируется исключение NullReferenceException.
2. > Если ссылка указывает на объект, не являющийся упакованным значением требуемого значимого типа, генерируется исключение
   >   InvalidCastException1

Из Рихтера "CLR VIA 4.5"

Comment: Ну что-ж, спасибо) Буду знать

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю, насколько это более элегантно, но:

```
int a = 1;
object b = a;
double c = (int)b;
```

Какой тип упаковали, в тот и распаковываете. Эквивалентно `double c = (double)(int)b;` но приведение к `double` неявное.

Суть в том, что вы должны знать, какой тип вы упаковали в object.
Если не знаете какой тип, то можно проверить

```
int a = 1;
object b = a;
double c;
if (b is int)
    c = (int)b;
else
    throw new ArgumentException();
```